# Time Synchronizer with more than 9 incoming channels

Tags: ros, synchronization, timesynchronizer, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to synchronize 32 image topics, which then trigger one common callback function. Unfortunately message_filters::TimeSynchronizer only supports up to 9 topics, and so does message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime.
I found a note to a DynamicTimeSynchronizer in the source code, but apparently it's not implemented yet.
Is there an easy solution / workaround?

Cheers,
Andreas

Btw: Is there a reason why the number of topics is hard coded?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37535/time-synchronizer-with-more-than-9-incoming-channels/) by [andreas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1031/andreas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-29**:
The reason why it is hard-coded is that the time synchronizer works on topics with different type, i.e. it needs to be templated on all types. Since C++ didn't support variadic templates before C++11, hard-coding was the only possibility.

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-10-08**:
Hi, I was just wondering if it is a good idea to divide the problem in 2 steps. i.e first synchronize 8 images and make them a new custom topic lets say "Image8" and publish it. That way the Image set of 32 is divided in to 4 sets. and then we can synchronize the 4 "Image8" topics aftwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your options are limited.

You can either use C++11 to extend the current `TimeSynchronizer`. By using cpp macros properly, you can make this mechanism totally optional which would allow to achieve your goal without imposing C++11 to the whole ROS community. It would be a reasonable design choice IMHO.

Another possibility is writing a `TimeSynchronizer` for several instance of **one** type. It is possible to do so without relying on metaprogramming. In your case, it would be sufficient.

Both would be interesting addition to `message_filters`, I think. But you'll probably need to fork the class you use by copying them into your own project as long as they are not integrated and part of the official release.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3